# Как удалить данные из структуры?

Tags: c

Есть задание:

> Дано информацию про 5 студентов. Структура имеет вид: имя, номер телефона и сколько лет. Найти и удалить данные про студентов, которым меньше 18 лет. Начальные данные записать в один бинарный файл, а новые результаты в другой.

Но проблема в том, что не знаю как удалить данные про студентов, которым меньше 18 лет.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код и конкретнее объясните, что не получается.

Comment: *не знаю как удалить данные* - **удалить** часть данных  означает **читать** исходные данные все подряд, но вот **писать** только те данные, где возраст больше 18 лет., а остальное **не** писать.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно говоря, в чем проблема? Алгоритм примерно следующий:

1. Считываем данные о студенте
2. Записываем информацию о нем в файл с начальными данными
3. Смотрим возраст:

   - Если больше 18, пишем в файл, содержащий список студентов, которым больше 18
   - Если нет - не пишем ничего